# How to prevent Wordpress from uncommenting php in the <head> tag?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to build a Wordpress website to take payments using Forte as a payment processor.

I was told to place the following code in the header.php in WordPress:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$api_access_id = OURSECRETID;
$api_secret_key = ORUSECRETKEY;
$location_id = OURSECRETLOCATION;
$version = '2.0';
//date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
//$unixtime = strtotime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
//$millitime = microtime(true) * 1000;
//$utc = number_format(($millitime * 10000) + 621355968000000000 , 0, '.', '');
$utc = get_utc();

$token_array = ['customer_token' => '', 'paymethod_token' => ''];

function get_utc()
{
    $utc = '';

    try
    {
        //do CURL stuff here
        $curl_handle = curl_init("https://sandbox.forte.net/checkout/getUTC?callback=?");
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);

        $start = stripos($curl_response, "(", 0) + 1;
        $end = stripos($curl_response, ")", $start);

        $utc = substr($curl_response, $start, $end - $start);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "<br/>An exception occurred. The exception is: " . $e . "<br/>";
        $utc = 0;
    }

    return $utc;
}

function reset_tokens($token_array)
{
    $token_array['customer_token'] = '';
    $token_array['paymethod_token'] = '';

    return ($token_array);
}

function calculate_hmac_md5_hash($api_access_id, $method, $version, $totalamount, $utc, $ordernumber, $customer_token, $paymethod_token, $api_secret_key)
{
    $data = "$api_access_id|$method|$version|$totalamount|$utc|$ordernumber|$customer_token|$paymethod_token";
    $hash = hash_hmac('md5', $data, $api_secret_key);
    return $hash;
}
?>
<head>  
    <script>
        function invoke_FCO_modal()
        {
                        document.getElementById('btn1').click();                                          
        }
        function oncallback(e)
        {
                        $('#response').html(e.data);
        }                             
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.forte.net/checkout/v2/js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The problem is that I get this in the header of the website as plain text:

```
'', 'paymethod_token' => '']; function get_utc() { $utc=''; try { //do CURL stuff here $curl_handle=curl_init("https://sandbox.forte.net/checkout/getUTC?callback=?"); curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE); curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); $curl_response = curl_exec($curl_handle); curl_close($curl_handle); $start=stripos($curl_response, "(", 0) + 1; $end=stripos($curl_response, ")", $start); $utc=substr($curl_response, $start, $end-$start); } catch (Exception $e) { echo "
An exception occurred. The exception is: " . $e . "
"; $utc=0; } return $utc; } function reset_tokens($token_array) { $token_array['customer_token']=''; $token_array['paymethod_token']=''; return ($token_array); } function calculate_hmac_md5_hash($api_access_id, $method, $version, $totalamount, $utc, $ordernumber, $customer_token, $paymethod_token, $api_secret_key) { $data = "$api_access_id|$method|$version|$totalamount|$utc|$ordernumber|$customer_token|$paymethod_token"; $hash = hash_hmac('md5',$data,$api_secret_key); return $hash; } ?>
```

I can't figure out why this happens or how to prevent it from happening. I'm using the standard 2020 WordPress theme.

What to do?

Comment: Is WP, or PHP, working at all?  I mean showing your posts, can you login, anything?  If not, I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page.

Comment: Yes the site is otherwise working correctly. It's what GoDaddy calls a "managed WordPress site". It's just that it doesn't work correctly when I place the code in the head tag inside the header.php file in my 2020 WordPress theme (or any other theme for that matter. I've tried different themes, but they are not any easier to understand. I know Python, but html and php is not foreign to me, which is why I can't see why it's not working as instructed.

Comment: Strange. Shouldn't make any difference but try moving the `<?php ?>` block *above* the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so it is before any html.  What does the generated HTML look like, I mean if you view source?